# Application to show CPU and RAM usage in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, monitoring

I have a Windows 8 PC. Am testing different types of softwares like WinRAR, 7-ZIP, media converters, antiviruses etc. As part of the testing I need to know how much RAM and CPU is used by each application. Currently I use Task Manager to view the CPU and RAM usage. I need to know whether there is some application that shows the amount of CPU and RAM used.

1. It should be free and light weight.
2. It should provide graphical and numerical display according to usage.
3. Primarily I need to view CPU and RAM usage only, but additional features like Disk usage, Processor Core details are also acceptable.
4. In Windows 7 there was a widget to know CPU and RAM usage. So I prefer an application that looks like this widget. The application should use only a limited area of display. Also this application should run all the time.

Can anyone suggest a good application ?

Comment: Have you checked [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default)?  They got lots of free utilities.

Comment: @rrirower It is not what am looking for.

Comment: @ManuJacob Could you expand upon what Sysinternals doesn't do that you want? That could be useful in narrowing down what software would meet your needs.

Comment: @Undo Which of the Sysinternal do that I want ?

Comment: @ManuJacob I hope I helped. Gadgets is a really useful aspect, it was ignored in latter versions of windows but we can still use them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you wish to use it as a widget/gadget I found [this](http://8gadgetpack.net/) website which helps you run gadgets on windows 8.
[image]

I narrowed the huge list of available gadgets to a list of the ones you might need given your specs:

1. All CPU Meter - AddGadgets.com
2. Control System - AddGadgets.com CPU
3. Meter - Microsoft DriveInfo - Kris Thompson
4. Drives Monitor - Igor M.
5. Bushin Drives Meter - AddGadgets.com
6. Glassy CPU Monitor - Helmut
7. Buhler Glassy Network Monitor - Helmut Buhler
8. GPU Meter -  AddGadgets.com
9. Multi Meter - SFkilla
10. Network Meter - AddGadgets.com
11. Network Monitor II - Igor M. Bushin
12. Power Status - Orbmu2k Remove
13. System Monitor II - Igor M. Bushin Top
14. Process Monitor - Igor M. Bushin

**Edit Oh, and it's free

Answer (score 3):

According to your requirement the best tool that I can recommend for you to use is **Resource Monitor** in windows operating system,because its great way to find out about the resources your system uses and to see what applications and services are making the most use of your system.you can refer the screenshot in the Overview tab. It shows a snapshot of your system's resource usage, including CPU use, disk use, network use and memory use.

*Type resmon at the Start screen and then click the resmon.exe icon*

[image: Resource Monitor]

Comment: Is it possible to use it as a widget ?

Comment: @ManuJacob This cannot be used as a widget,and based on your question you cannot expect any detailed view on a widget this is why I suggested this